# Не понимаю результат выполнения программы

Tags: java

```
public class Solution {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         int a = 5;
         int b = 10;
         a += ++b;
         System.out.println(a + b)
     } 
}
```

Вывод:

> 27

Почему так?

Comment: Разбейте на шаги и выполните их по очереди выводя состояние переменных.

Comment: Как вы получили вывод, если ваш код не компилируется?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Давайте разобьём выражение

```
a += ++b;
```

на эквивалентное, но понятное

```
++b; // b = 10 + 1 = 11
a = a + b; // a = 5 + 11 = 16

System.out.println(a + b) // 11 + 16 = 27
```

Answer (score 1):

Инкремент (`++`) перед переменной увеличивает её на единицу до подсчёта результата выражения. То есть, когда программа считает `a += ++b`, сначала b увеличится на единицу, и только потом будет выполняться оператор `+=`.
Запись `a += b` эквивалентна записи `a = a + b`.

И тогда получается такой порядок действий:

`++b` -> b = 11

`a += b` -> `a = a + b` -> a = 5 + 11 = 16

`a + b` -> 11 + 16 = 27